# Making a view displayed on top of other views and always onscreen

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I have this layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <TextView
            style="@style/MyTextStyle"
            android:id="@+id/MessageTextView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
            <ImageButton
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_angry"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/AngryImageButton"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/BottomLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_below="@+id/FacesHolderFrameLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom">
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_chart_white_48dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:id="@+id/StatisticsImageButton"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which in general is an imageview that takes the whole screen and acts as a background image, the above it i have a linearlayout (**MainLinearLayout**) that hold vertically a textview, an imagebutton (**AngryImageButton**) and another linearlayout (**BottomLinearLayout**) that is just display a small image (like the logo) horizontally centered.

I want to be able to change programatically the size of the **AngryImageButton** and the **BottomLinearLayout** to be displayed in the bottom of the screen and to be always visible. I mean to be on top of the other views.

Right now the **BottomLinearLayout** appears in the center and below the **MainLinearLayout** and if i make the **AngryImageButton** very large, it pushes below the **BottomLinearLayout** until its not visible in the screen at all, i  don't want that. I want it to be at the bottom, and always visible.

How i can accomplish that? Also i want the layout to **work in both orientations**

Comment: Hi. Yes, can you provide a screenshot and explain a little bit further?

Comment: I have add an image, the small box is the AngryImageButton and below it is the BottomLinearLayout  and behind all is imgDisplay that displayed this background pattern image. this isnt exactly my layout, my layout is more complex but i have simplified it because i believe the case is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring `View` to front, you can use

```
myView.bringToFront()
```

or You can make use of ViewCompat and set its translation Z like below.

```
ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, 1)
```

here's the doc for `bringToFront()` [bringToFront()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#bringToFront())

Comment: oh nice, so you suggest me to bring view to front and maybe place it to bottom with something like this? android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"